# How to obtain geographic location (data) via a Twitter Streams api query?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am using the twitter streaming api and have created a stream about `#javascript` but I want to pitch my tweets on a map.

Every response I get in any of the geo or locations field is `null`. So I need some form of elevated privilege or is the tweets location something I'm not allowed to query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no extra privilege for this. You have a few options, all of which yield a very low percentage of geo-located tweets.

The `geo` field used to be filled with coordinates for about 1% of all tweets. Twitter this year began returning even fewer tweets with `geo` coordinates.

These days, you will get a small percentage of tweets with `place`, which contains the coordinates for a bounding box. This may not be useful for you if you want to map a point, although you could calculate the center of the box and map that. Also, `place` is manually selected when tweeting, so it's meaning is questionable.

Your last option is the `location` field which users fill in about half the time. It's a fixed location that the user identifies with. Often it's some sarcastic comment. Still, `location` is usable if you send it to a geolocation service which will return its latitude and longitude. Like `place`, `location` has questionable significance.

Comment: Thought as much! Thanks